# Silent notification/ Blank Push Notification not updating pass added to Apple Wallet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, wallet

Hi my project is based on Asp.Net MVC 4.5 and
I am having issue while sending blank push notification such that pass added to the user
wallet got updated .
There's no error in logs and its also working fine while debugging.
But when i hard refresh the pass it got updated .
It was working but suddenly stopped working recently.
I am using following method to send Blank Push / Silent Notification

```
 public void BlankPushNotificationAPNS(string deviceID, string org_key)
 {
     int port = 2195;
     String hostname = "gateway.push.apple.com";
     DataObject.Configuration config = ConfigurationRepository.Instance.getCofigurationByOrgKey(org_key);
     String certificatePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Certificates/") + config.wallet_cert_name;
     //Utility.Logger.LogMsg("Certificate Path : " + certificatePath);
     byte[] certificateBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath);
     //using (var webClient = new WebClient())
     //{
     //    certificateBytes = webClient.DownloadData(certificatePath);
     //}
     //Utility.Logger.LogMsg("Certificate Bytes : " + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(certificateBytes));
     X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, config.wallet_cert_password);
     X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);
     //X509Certificate cert = GetAppleServerCert(thumbprint);
     //Utility.Logger.LogMsg("certificate read");
     TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
     SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
     //Utility.Logger.LogMsg("certificate read ssl");
     try
     {
         //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
         sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
         MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
         BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
         writer.Write((byte)0);
         writer.Write((byte)0);
         writer.Write((byte)32);

         writer.Write(StringToByteArray(deviceID.ToUpper()));
         String payload = "{\"aps\":\"\"}";
         writer.Write((byte)0);
         writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);
         byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
         writer.Write(b1);
         writer.Flush();
         byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
         sslStream.Write(array);
         
         sslStream.Flush();
         client.Close();
     }
     catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException ex)
     {
        Utility.Logger.BlankPushLogger("Method:BlankPushNotificationAPNS,AuthenticationException", ex.Message + ", deviceID_" + deviceID + ", org name " + config.org_name_without_spaces);
         client.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
                         Utility.Logger.BlankPushLogger("Method:BlankPushNotificationAPNS,Exception", e.Message + ", deviceID_" + deviceID + ", org name " + config.org_name_without_spaces);
         client.Close();
     }
 }
```

Is there some changes done by apple in certificates or something else.
Since it's working and stopped recently.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you been making a lot of updates to test the pass?  If so, your device might be throttling updates.  You can turn off throttling on your device through the developer menu.  Seeing that you have it working while debugging, I assume that you are connecting to APNS with the PassTypeID certificate and that it is not expired or revoked.

Comment: No it is not even working in debug also.
Its working when i hard refresh the pass from device